# Can I override WP site's CSS on one page/body section?

Tags: html, css, shortcode

Working on a site with some wonky CSS - I have had this issue before, but trying to install simple gravity forms poll on a simple page with their shortcode....CSS is preventing the actual question content from showing up. Is there some magic code that I can use in the `wysiwyg` text/code view before the shortcode, that will override the `css` that is messing this up? Looking for a quick fix if one exists.

Shortcode:

```
[gravityform action="polls" id="6" mode="poll" style="green" cookie="1 week"
 show_results_link="true" display_results="true" percentages="true" counts="true"]
```

[Test page](http://qryde.com/qryde-poll/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Right-click on the element on the page and you'll see the option to inspect the element. This will show you the class names and styles applied to that element. You then write your own CSS to target these classes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Do I have to edit this in the CSS or is there something that I can add specifically to this content area in the text/code box? I'm super nervous to edit the CSS as I know very little about it. Altering the CSS file would alter the entire site, correct? My luck I will take the whole thing down...

Comment: Just back up before your changes and go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dev Tools of your browser to inspect the element, and see that there is css rule `display: none`. Change it to:

```
.gform_wrapper label {
    display: initial;
}
```

And if it has no effect, try to add `!important`.

*EDIT:*

If you are afraid of affecting other pages of your site, you can use the unique class name that the WP set to the `body` element of each page (you can find it in the source, `page-id-2720`). And it will look like:

```
.page-id-2720 .gform_wrapper label {
    display: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do I have to edit this in the CSS or is there something that I can add specifically to this content area in the text/code box? I'm super nervous to edit the CSS as I know very little about it. Altering the CSS file would alter the entire site, correct? My luck I will take the whole thing down...

Comment: You are welcome :) don't be nervous. I'll edit the answer with explanation now.